# WCF Data Service throws “Operation could destabilize the runtime” Exception

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-data-services

My goal is to expose a SQL Server 2008 table as XML/JSON via IIS.

I followed a [few(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg617675) [videos(2)](http://app.looplogic.com/azgroups/odata-begins) to stand up a WCF Data Services web app and while the $metadata page works, attempting to view the actual data causes an exception:

```
Operation could destabilize the runtime.
System.Security.VerificationException
```

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBSf0.jpg)

I started from this VS2013 [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inySP.jpg) with .NET 4.5.1 and Entity Framework 6.1.2 - more specific package versions below.

On the chance a NuGet package is causing the VerificationException, should I try removing all the NuGet packages, and adding only EntityFramework (and whatever that depends on)?

Appreciate any ideas, thanks guys!

```
Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                                              
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                              
Antlr                          3.5.0.2              ANother Tool for Language Recognition, is a language tool that provides a framework for constructing recognizers, in...
bootstrap                      3.3.2                Sleek, intuitive, and powerful mobile first front-end framework for faster and easier web development.                 
EntityFramework                6.1.2                Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended data access technology for new applications.                               
jQuery                         2.1.3                jQuery is a new kind of JavaScript Library....                                                                         
jQuery.Validation              1.13.1               This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation trivial, while offering lots of option for customization....
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc           5.2.3                This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way t...
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor         3.2.3                This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET Web Pages. ASP.NET Web Pages and the new Razor syntax provi...
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimi... 1.1.3                ASP.NET Optimization introduces a way to bundle and optimize CSS and JavaScript files.                                 
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages      3.2.3                This package contains core runtime assemblies shared between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Pages.                        
Microsoft.Data.Edm             5.6.3                Classes to represent, construct, parse, serialize and validate entity data models. Targets .NET 4.0, Silverlight 4. ...
Microsoft.Data.OData           5.6.3                Classes to serialize, deserialize and validate OData payloads. Enables construction of OData producers and consumers...
Microsoft.Data.Services        5.6.3                Fully-featured server API for responding to OData queries and consuming/producing OData payloads. Supports OData v3....
Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.3                LINQ-enabled client API for issuing OData queries and consuming OData payloads. Supports OData v3. Targets .NET 4.0,...
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusiv... 3.2.3                jQuery plugin that unobtrusively sets up jQuery.Validation.                                                            
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure   1.0.0.0              This package contains the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure assembly that lets you dynamically register HTTP modules at r...
Modernizr                      2.8.3                Modernizr adds classes to the <html> element which allow you to target specific browser functionality in your styles...
Newtonsoft.Json                6.0.8                Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET                                                         
Respond                        1.4.2                The goal of this script is to provide a fast and lightweight (3kb minified / 1kb gzipped) script to enable responsiv...
System.Spatial                 5.6.3                Contains classes and methods that facilitate geography and geometry spatial operations. Targets .NET 4.0, Silverligh...
WebGrease                      1.6.0                Web Grease is a suite of tools for optimizing javascript, css files and images.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've the same packages and that update installed, but I had the same error.
I've solved this way:

1.Install the latest Nuget package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider following the guide on that page;

2.Replace DataService with EntityFrameworkDataService, say in your WcfDataService1.svc:

public class WcfDataService1 : EntityFrameworkDataService

However I don't know if it is the best parctice to do because some ms tutorials don't say anything about EntityFrameworkDataService

others do: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/08/18/wcf-data-services-entity-framework-provider-is-updated-with-wcf-data-service-5-6-2.aspx

Comment: Thanks this ended up being the closest answer. In case this helps save someone time:

Using the **EntityFrameworkDataService** object requires adding this line to the using block:


using System.Data.Services.Providers;

Answer (score 1):

I went though such a painfull process of decorating all my POCOs with [DataServiceKey("ID")] and many many other option. This was not necessary at all. Just inherit your service from EntityFrameworkDataService instead of DataService. I know that the Visual Studio templates adds it as DataService<>. So please do the following and it will fix the issue:

```
public class QueryServices : EntityFrameworkDataService<MathContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue at my workplace.  The cause was the use of lambda expressions in constructors.  Installing this fixed the problem
[kb2748645](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: Thanks for posting, I tried your link but the install was blocked for some reason.

http://imgur.com/8X8YgCm